# Grab specific Variable String from URL With PHP

Tags: php, redirect

I Have this line which catch the value of the paramater ( search_query )

`$search_query       = $filter->get('search_query', 'STRING', 'GET');`

Example when the Url is
mydomain.com/search/articles?search_query=**Test**

then the $search_query = '**Test**'

But now i want to Catch the same keyword from this links

mydomain.com/search/articles/**Test**

mydomain.com/search/articles/**Test**?t=monthly&type=public

so How can i do that ?

Comment: Use the explode function? explode the string on the / and pick the right index from the array that is returns

Comment: Are you using a framework? Where is that `->get()` method defined? That class may have some other URL methods you can use.